# Accidentlly dropped DB table in Django project. How to re-do migrations?

Tags: django, database, django-migrations

I've accidentally delated a table from the DB (model AboutUs).
Usually I'll delete djando.migrations reccords for this migration (0063), delete the migration file and run makemigrations and migrate commands.

1. First problem is that there are like 20 migrations after the one in question(0063) and in them there are fields modified, added, removed for the same model
2. Seccond problem is that I'm not alone working on the project and it is shared in GitHub. If I delete the migration files there will be conflicts with the origin DB

Is there a way to run migrations related only to specific model?

Any other ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For a one-off solution, you can copy all the migration operations that are touching this table in the database to a new migration (doesn't have to be numbered), move all other migrations out from the migrations directory and run that migration by itself. After it succeeds, you can remove this migration, the entry it from your `django_migrations` table and restore your previous migrations.

To create this temporary migration, you can just copy over your initial migration, omitting the contents of the `operations` list. To fill the operations, you have to go through your existing migrations and copy the relevant operations.

For the future, you can secure yourself by doing a database backup before any manual database operations.